# What's the best practice/ a secure way for saving and processing a password of a plugin's option page?

Tags: wordpress, api, security, plugins, passwords

First of all, I'm not a security expert and new to form validation, password storing and wp plugin development. Any wp plugin tutorial I've been looking at never had a chapter about API passwords. Googling for wordpress password issues didn't return any satisfying results. So that's why I'm asking here.

I want to create a custom Wordpress Plugin which works with a Soap API of another page. To use the Soap API a login is needed. So the Wordpress built in functions `add_option()`, `update_option()` and `get_option()` are all working with plain text.

But I know that in the wp_config file authentication keys can be saved. But how to use them in an option page form to encrypt the password? And would it be possible just to store them in the database, decrypt it and use it in the backend but not showing it on the options page if the user visits that page again. So that the password field just has some black spots in it (not the same amount of the chars of the pass) and the password option only is updated if something is written into that field.

Normally the code is like this:

```
register_setting( 'my_plugins_option', 'my_options', 'my_validation_function' );

$options = array(
    'user' = > 'name',
    'password' = > 'pass',
    //... other options
) 
update_option( 'my_plugins_option', $options );
```

But how could I make this more secure? I've seen many plugin examples but nothing was about storing passwords. I'm looking for something like this:

```
function my_validation_function($input){
    if($input['password']=='•••••'){
        //use the default value of the database if nothing was changed
        $old_options=get_option('my_plugins_option');
        $input['password']=some_decrypting_function($old_options['password']);
    }
    else{
        //use the password sent from the form
        $password=esc_sql(some_encrypting_function($input['password']));            
    }
    // ... validate the other inputs
    update_option( 'my_plugins_soap_api_pass', $password );
}
```

P.S.: This code is not tested yet of course because I don't know how to work with passwords in wordpress plugins and so I wanted to ask for the best practices first.

The other question is: If the modified version of the code from above would work and the password is saved once and never loaded into the Dashboard frontend again (just showing this: '•••••' once typed in) would it be save to work with the get_option() function, decrypt the password and use it in the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple recommendations.  They aren't specific to WP, but can apply.

1) Save an encrypted password in the options table (use whatever encrypting function you want, just don't write your own)

2) In the options page, simply do NOT output the password. Leave that field blank, and don't require it to be entered if there is already a password stored in the database.

3) Only decrypt the password retrieved from the options table just prior to actually needing it in code.